# How to get the executed command of a process which has completed successfully using the PID?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, ps, background-process

I have small script, abc.ksh that takes 3 parameter
e.g abc.ksh ${a} ${b} ${c}

I will read from a config file with 'n' no of entires and I will execute abc.ksh 'n' times in parallel using a for loop.
E.g

```
export pids=()
for file in `cat config.txt`
do
    a=`echo ${file}|awk -F"|" '{ print $1 }'`
    b=`echo ${file}|awk -F"|" '{ print $2 }'`
    c=`echo ${file}|awk -F"|" '{ print $3 }'`   
    nohup ksh abc.ksh ${a} ${b} ${c} &
    pids+=("$!")
done
```

Next, I need to check the completion of each job(based on the pid) and perform the next action item for that particular job.
E.g

```
export cnt=0
while[ $cnt -eq `wc -l config.txt`]; do
  export tmp=()
  for p in ${pids[*]}; do
    if[[ ! -d /proc/${p} ]]; then
      wait ${p}
      echo "Process completed with Process ID ${p}; exit code: $?"
      if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
        ***<Need to get the executed command "
        nohup ksh abc.ksh {a} {b} {c}" for the successfully completed PID>.***
      else      
    else
      echo "Process with Process ID ${p} Still running."
      tmp+=("${p}")
  done
  pids+=( ${tmp[*]})
done
```

How can I get that?

Comment: You'd need to have other arrays to track the parameters for each pid in the same order.

Comment: Please show a sample of your `config.txt`.  There's probably a much easier way to do this, possibly involving `perl` or `python` (i.e. this looks like a possible [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me)

Comment: Your script has syntax errors; `[` and `[[` require surrounding spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I will not comment too much on the structure or contents of the script other than noticing that you are putting the PIDs into the `pids` array in a sequential manner.

You are then waiting on these same PIDs is the same order.

This means that the command that you wait for in step `n` of the loop will be using the parameters on line `n` of `config.txt`.

The only thing that would cause problems are your forays into the `/proc` filesystem.  This is not needed. You also need to check the condition on the outer loop (`$cnt` will not be equal to the number of lines in the `config.txt` file on the first iteration, for example).